# Should I register caches when I know in longer perspective I will move?

Tags: geocaching

I've registered some caches in Poland. It strike me that reviewer from GeoCaching was asking how I'm supposed to service caches far from my home location. In the meantime I moved to Germany, which made caches registered near my 'home' location less serviceable than those register 'far from', but near my family location.

I'd like to register some caches here in Germany, but I know, that it is quite probable I will  change my location in a few years, and probably I will never have permanent 'home' location.

What should I do? I would like to register some caches, but I know I could service them no longer that a few years. Am I expected not to registered any caches at all, or I could create mountain caches, which are normally community-services? What proceeding will be accepted by geocaching community?

To be clear, I'm not asking for personal advice, but for general guidelines to obey in such cases.

Comment: Couldn't you transfer stewardship to a fellow geocacher before you move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that if you can service them for a couple of years then you should definitely register them.

At the end of that period, you can always deregister/delete and create community caches.

As long as you handle the changes in a sensible way - ie not abandoning a cache - then I can't see that there would be a problem.

Additionally, as @DonBranson commented - you can always hand over stewardship :-)

Comment: well community caches are an unofficial concept, but it is functioning in mountains in Poland, for example, people are making new logbooks, containers for other caches etc.

Comment: Yep - there are a couple of places they seem to be accepted. It does allow individuals on the move to create a cache despite knowing they will not be able to maintain it in the future.